# Are bulk array operations faster than sequential operations?

Tags: arrays, vector, language-agnostic, arraylist, time-complexity

Say I am given an array, and a function called `replace`:

```
void replace(from, to, items[])
```

whose job is to replace the array elements in the range `[from, to)` with the elements in `items`.
I'll assume the maximum size of the array is known beforehand, so I can ensure the array will never overflow.

My question is, if I am given a list of replacements (e.g. elements of the form `(from, to, items)`), is it possible for me to obtain the final resulting array with a **faster** time complexity than performing each operation sequentially?

In other words, is there any advantage to knowing the sequence of operations beforehand, or is it no better than being given each operation one by one (in terms of the asymptotic time complexity)?

**Note:** It seems like the question is confusing; I did **not** intend to imply that the number of elements replacing a given range is the same as the size of that range! It could be fewer or more, causing shifting, and the point of the question was was to ask if knowing them beforehand could avoid extra work like shifting in the worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may not be what you are finding, but using [Rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) can shorten the time-complexity. It provides operation on string like concat without "shift"ing actual array. (not needed to be a string of char. arbitary type of element can be used as alphabets)

According to Wikipedia (...Because I have not ever used it yet), Rope is a balaced binary tree of fragmented string. A rope represents long string concatenated all fragmented string.
your replace() function can be implemented using Split() and Concat() operation on the rope,
both operations takes only O(log(n)) time. Here, I put n as the length of the long string the rope represents.

To get normal array, rope can be converted in O(n) time using Report() operation.

so the answer is: There is a algorithm faster than sequencially applies string operation.

- convert given array to a rope
- apply every replace job on the rope. each operation runs in O(log(n)) and does not copy actual array items.
- convert the processed rope to a real array (this causes copy of all items).
- return it.

Answer (score 0):

It's always linear, down to `memcpy`'s level. The only way to speed it up is trade time for space - override the array subscript operator so that elements between `from` and `to` point to elements in `items` rather than the original array, which is not a good solution under any circumstances.